# scrollTop does not work after Axios response

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, vue.js, axios

I am having an issue in building a real-time chat using Laravel (with Vue.js, Pusher, Echo).
Here I have 3 methods:

```
created() {
    this.fetchMessages();
    this.group = $('#group').data('group');
    Echo.private('chat.' + this.group)
        .listen('MessageSent', (e) => {
            this.messages.push({
                text: e.message.text,
                user: e.user,
                author: e.user.name,
                avatar: e.message.avatar
            });
        });
},

methods: {
    fetchMessages() {
        axios.get('/chat/check/' + this.group).then(response => {
            this.messages = response.data;

        });
    },

    addMessage(message) {
        axios.post('/chat/add', message).then(response => {
            this.messages.push(response.data);
        });

    }
}`
```

After these methods I need to scroll my `<div id="chat">` to bottom. I tried a lot of options like:
`document.getElementById('chat').scrollTop=9999`

The same using jQuery `$('#chat')...`,

Some plugins like `vue-scroll-chat` and same for jQuery, but none of them worked. This command doesn't work in methods `fetchMessages` and `addMessage`
and...

```
addMessage(message) {
        axios.post('/chat/add', message).then(response => {
            this.messages.push(response.data);
            document.getElementById('chat').scrollTop=9999;
        });
    }
```

doesn't work. How can I fix it?

Comment: UPD: Maybe i have wrong conception of chat. Because i don`t see any scroll effects and other after sending a message in popular socials. May be there are another ways to make nice list of messages and appending of message?

Comment: What does the template look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to add the `document.getElementById('chat').scrollTop=9999;` to a `Vue.$nextTick` so that the information has time to appear and effect the element before the scroll effect is actuated.

You may also want to add a `ref="chat"` to your chat element so you can reference scrollTop via the vue reference; it would look something like this

```
addMessage(message) {
    axios.post('/chat/add', message).then(response => {
        this.messages.push(response.data)
        this.$nextTick(
            () => {
                this.$refs.chat.scrollTop=9999;
            }
        )
    })
}
```